# mudar consulta da página 10 em 10 segundos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Tenho uma página que lista todos os meus eventos da tabela evento (`tbl_eventos`). Quero listar todos os eventos da primeira semana do ano, passado 10 segundos, lista todos os eventos na segunda semana do ano, e por aí adiante.

Na minha tabela eventos tenho os seguintes campos: `id_evento; nome; data`

Para fazer a consulta estou a usar `php` e `mysql`. Estou a pensar usar ajax, mas não sei como fazer para atualizar o conteúdo de 10 em 10 segundos e como enviar a data que vou procurar.

Comment: Os eventos seriam exibidos mais ou menos como se fosse um slider? Coloque o código fonte que você já fez.

Comment: Então, não sei até onde é interessante ficar fazendo requisições pro banco e pro servidor de 10 em 10 segundos, no meu ponto de vista o mais eficiente seria você trazes a consulta com tudo o que será exibido de uma vez, ai com javaScript você ficar alterando o conteúdo do que será exibido

Comment: @rray, sim, vamos imaginar que seria um slider mas na verdade vai atualizar o conteudo da página

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supondo que você utilize jQuery.

Javascript:

```
jQuery(function(){

    var semana = 0;

    var itv = window.setInterval(function(){
        jQuery.get("consulta.php?semana="+semana, function(data){
            jQuery("#container").html(data);
        });

        semana++;

    },10000);
});
```

PHP:

```
/*Supondo que você já possua a conexão com o banco de dados*/

$semana = $_GET["semana"];

/*Supondo que a variável $semana seja 0, a consulta irár retornar todos os registros da primeira semana do ano, independente do ano. Para restringir, utilize por exemplo, 'AND YEAR(data) = 2014'*/
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_eventos WHERE WEEK(data) = {$semana}");

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ){
    echo $row->id_evento . " - " .  $row->nome . " - " . $row->data . "<br>";
}
```

Não testei, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: a variável "$offset" leva a data? os dias? assim como posso limitar a consulta por dias, aumentando uma semana de cada vez?

Comment: esqueci desse detalhe, vou corrigir a resposta

Comment: Resposta corrigida @pc_oc

Comment: o código só corre nos uma vez, ou seja, o contador não se está sempre repetindo

Comment: Troca o `setTimeout` por `setInterval`

Comment: Essa é uma maneira de fazer isso, mas não é a melhor... o correto acredito que seria fazer uma única consulta e via javascript, ir alternando os resultados, como o @Marcelo Bonifazio comentou.

Comment: alterei window.setInterval(function() por setInterval(function() e já deu. obrigado!